# A trivial problem in calculus

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

Try to compute $$\int\frac{dx}{x\ln x}$$
I compute it this way: first we have $x>0$.
\begin{align*}
\int\frac{dx}{x\ln x}
&=\int\frac{d(\ln x)}{\ln x}\\
&=\ln|\ln x|+C
\end{align*}
But the answer to the problem is $\ln\ln x+C$. Which one is right? Thanks!

**Source** Григорий Михайлович Фихтенгольц

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both and none. Your solution is a primitive both on $(0,1)$ and on $(1,+\infty)$. The answer of the book is a primitive only on $(1,+\infty)$.
Therefore, I'd say that *your* answer is better and more complete.

Comment: Although the constant of integration can be different on each of $(0,1)$ and $(1, \infty)$.

Comment: Yes, of course. Anyway, both $(0,1)$ and $(1,+\infty)$ are connected sets, so *one* primitive is enough.